# "index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1" in python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I seem to be having an indexing problem? I do not know how to interpret this error... :/ I think it has to do with how I initialized u.

I have this 3x3 G matrix that I created using the variable u (a vector, x - y). I just made a zero matrix for now bc I'm not quite sure how to code it yet, there are lots of partials and norms involved haha. x_j = (x_1 (j), x_2 (j), x_3 (j)) and y_j = (y_1 (j), y_2 (j), y_3 (j)). x and y are nx3 vectors. alpha_j is a 3x3 matrix. The A matrix is block diagonal matrix of size 3nx3n. I am having trouble with the W matrix (size 3nx3n, where the (i,j)th block is the 3x3 matrix given by alpha_i*G_[ij]*alpha_j).

```
def G(u):

    u1 = u[0]
    u2 = u[1]
    u3 = u[2]
    g = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],complex)  

    return g

def W(x, y, k, alpha, A):

    # initialization
    n = x.shape[0] # the number of x vextors 
    result = np.zeros([3*n,3*n],complex)
    u = np.matlib.zeros((n, 3)) # u = x - y 
    print(u)
    num_in_blocks = n

    # variables
    a_i = alpha_j(alpha, A)
    a_j = alpha_j(alpha, A)

    for i in range(0, 2):
        x1 = x[i] # each row of x
        y1 = y[i] # each row of y
        for j in range(0, n-1):
            u[i][j] = x1[j] - y1[j] # each row of x minus each row of y
        if i != j:
            block_result = a_i * G((u[i][j]), k) * a_j
            for k in range(num_in_blocks):
                for l in range(num_in_blocks):
                    result[3*i + k, 3*j + l] = block_result[i, j] 

    return result

def alpha_j(a, A):
    alph = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],complex)
    n = A.shape[0]
    rho = np.random.rand(n,1)
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        for j in range(0, n-1):
            alph[i,j] = (rho[i] * a * A[i,j])
    return alph

#------------------------------------------------------------------

# random case

def x(n):
    return np.random.randint(100, size=(n, 3))

def y(n):
    return np.random.randint(100, size=(n, 3))

# SYSTEM PARAMETERS

theta = 0 # can range from [0, 2pi)

chi = 10 + 1j

lam = 0.5 # microns (values between .4-.7)

k = (2 * np.pi)/lam # 1/microns

V_0 = (0.05)**3 # microns^3

K = k * np.array([[0], [np.sin(theta)], [np.cos(theta)]])

alpha = (V_0 * 3 * chi)/(chi + 3)

A = np.matlib.identity(3) 

#------------------------------------------------------------------

# TEST FUNCTIONS

w = W(x(3), y(3), k, alpha, A)
print(w)
```

I keep getting the error "invalid index to scalar variable." at the line u1 = u[0].

Comment: You shouldn't use that type of chained indexing with `numpy` arrays.  Also, an easy way to debug this would be to figure out what your shapes are at each step of the process, since they clearly are not what you expect them to be

Comment: @user3483203 what do you mean by chained indexing? this is the only way I know how to do it :/ thanks for the tip tho, I'll try that

Comment: Why are you using `np.matlib`?

Comment: Check the `shape` of the problem array, and index at the point.  If the axis has size 1, then you can only use [0] as the index.  Remember indexing is on the [0,n) range (just like `range(n)` and `np.arange(n)`).

Comment: @hpauli idk I fixed that lmao. I'll try that thanks

Answer (score 0):

`np.matlib` makes a `np.matrix`, a subclass of `np.ndarray`.  It's supposed to give a MATLAB feel, and (nearly) always produces a 2d array.  Its use in new code is being discouraged.

```
In [42]: U = np.matrix(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))                                    
In [43]: U                                                                           
Out[43]: 
matrix([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]])
```

Indexing with [0] picks the first row, but returns a 2d matrix.

```
In [44]: U[0]                                                                        
Out[44]: matrix([[0, 1, 2]])
In [45]: U[0].shape                                                                  
Out[45]: (1, 3)
```

Adding another [1] still indexes the first dimension (which is now size 1):

```
In [46]: U[0][1]                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Normally we index numpy arrays with a composite index:

```
In [47]: U[0,1]                                                                      
Out[47]: 1
```

If we make an `ndarray` instead:

```
In [48]: U = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)                                               
In [49]: U                                                                           
Out[49]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [50]: U[0]                                                                        
Out[50]: array([0, 1, 2])      # 1d
In [51]: U[0][1]               # works,                                                       
Out[51]: 1
In [52]: U[0,1]                # still preferable                                                      
Out[52]: 1
```